# loop tuple list - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, tuples

this works:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
   # food = tuple(food)
    for food in food:
        total += prices[food]

    return total 

print compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

But if I change food to anything else in the loop, for example X - for x in food - then python gives me below error (it only works with for food in food.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute-shopping.py", line 25, in <module>
    print compute_bill(shopping_list) 
  File "compute-shopping.py", line 21, in compute_bill
    total += prices[food]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is not related to using  tuple or list as key for dictionary ... or is it ?!

Comment: Please change the loop variable to something other than `food` as you are overwriting the earlier value of `food`

Comment: `for food in food` have you considered referring to its contents by a different name?

Comment: Is `food` a list or a string? Python seems to think it's a list, and you are using it to index a dictionary, which is a no-no. Dictionary keys must be immutable.

Comment: What do you mean by "change food to anything else"? What are the possible values of "anything else"? And what instance of `food` are you changing?

Comment: if I change food to foot_type or any other variable name, I get ' unhashable type: 'list' ; so the question is why For food in food loop only work and not For food_type in food ? or for x in food ?

Comment: Ooh, now I get it. If you do `for x in food`, then you have to do `total += prices[x]`. It was working before because you named the loop variable the same as the list, which, as others have told you, is a bad idea. And it was masking your lack of understanding of how the dictionary assignment should work. The index is each element of the list, and not the whole list. By the way, lambo477 correctly answers the question.

Comment: problem solved. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming food is a list, you just need to change the for loop to:

```
for food_type in food:
    total += prices[food_type]
```